# dpkg: error processing linux-image-amd64

Tags: linux, debian, dpkg, upgrade

After running

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install -f
dpkg --configure -a
```

I get the following Error:

```
 dpkg   --configure -a
    Setting up initramfs-tools (0.112) ...
    update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
    Setting up linux-image-3.8-2-amd64 (3.8.13-1) ...
    Running depmod.
    vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-3.8-2-amd64
    ) points to /boot/vmlinuz-3.8-2-amd64
     (/boot/vmlinuz-3.8-2-amd64) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.8-2-amd64.postinst line 268.
    The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.8-2-amd64
    Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.8-2-amd64 /boot/vmlinuz-3.8-2-amd64
    update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8-2-amd64

    gzip: stdout: No space left on device
    E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
    update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.8-2-amd64 with 1.
    run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
    Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.8-2-amd64.postinst line 696.
    dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.8-2-amd64 (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-amd64:
     linux-image-amd64 depends on linux-image-3.8-2-amd64; however:
      Package linux-image-3.8-2-amd64 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing linux-image-amd64 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
    update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64

    gzip: stdout: No space left on device
    E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
    update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64 with 1.
    dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     linux-image-3.8-2-amd64
     linux-image-amd64
     initramfs-tools
```

Output of df -h

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                 34G  8.4G   24G  27% /
udev                   10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                  50M  220K   50M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg0-root   34G  8.4G   24G  27% /
tmpfs                 5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                 100M     0  100M   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda2             179M   19M  151M  12% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg0-tmp   1.9G   35M  1.8G   2% /tmp
```

Output of df -i

```
df -i
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
rootfs         3555328 108372 3446956    4% /
udev            126899    331  126568    1% /dev
tmpfs           128378    273  128105    1% /run
/dev/sda3      3555328 108372 3446956    4% /
tmpfs           128378      4  128374    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           128378      2  128376    1% /run/shm
/dev/sda2        48672    304   48368    1% /boot
/dev/sda6       124928     21  124907    1% /tmp
```

Contents of /boot

```
ls -l /boot
total 77941
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   106193 Feb 25 04:02 config-2.6.32-5-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   130657 Feb  5  2012 config-3.2.0-1-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   128954 Jun 11  2012 config-3.2.0-2-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   128986 Jul 23  2012 config-3.2.0-3-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   129038 May 16 00:01 config-3.2.0-4-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   139218 May 16 15:15 config-3.8-2-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     5120 May 22 11:58 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9152728 Mar  3 18:16 initrd.img-2.6.32-5-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10103130 Mar 11  2012 initrd.img-3.2.0-1-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10144903 Jul 23  2012 initrd.img-3.2.0-2-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10153801 Nov 25 12:26 initrd.img-3.2.0-3-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10706204 May 22 11:56 initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    12288 Jan 16  2012 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1667905 Feb 25 04:02 System.map-2.6.32-5-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2073076 Feb  5  2012 System.map-3.2.0-1-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2091890 Jun 11  2012 System.map-3.2.0-2-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2095153 Jul 23  2012 System.map-3.2.0-3-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2105522 May 16 00:01 System.map-3.2.0-4-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2278502 May 16 15:15 System.map-3.8-2-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2426880 Feb 25 03:59 vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2779472 Feb  5  2012 vmlinuz-3.2.0-1-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2819504 Jun 11  2012 vmlinuz-3.2.0-2-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2822928 Jul 23  2012 vmlinuz-3.2.0-3-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2833376 May 15 23:58 vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2429168 May 16 15:13 vmlinuz-3.8-2-amd64
```

Comment: I think your server/system is getting out of disk space check for /boot partition . what is the output of df -h?

Comment: It says I have 24G free

Comment: No, you have 151M free on `/boot`.

Comment: Also check the output of `df -i`.

Comment: Added output of df -i, so how can I free space on /boot or allocate more space?

Comment: Could I not just remove some of the stuff in /boot ?

Comment: No please dont do that. You need to resize your boot partition, shrink any other parttion free up some space and aloocate it to boot partion.

Comment: apt-get install gparted is the good tool to resize your partitions.

Comment: Its non GUI, shall I use parted?

Comment: And don't shrink your partitions without having a backup.

Comment: It wont let me install parted because of the error.

Comment: Resizing `/boot` is problematic, because you may need to reinstall your bootloader after doing this, and may be left with an unbootable system. However, you may think about deleting some old kernel packages which were not used for a long time (if you did not need to revert to the old kernel for some months, you probably can remove it).

Comment: Check the output of dmesg. It should show the signs of corruption if there's something wrong with your filesystems.

Answer (score 7):

We see that `df` claims only 19MB is used in `/boot` and 151MB is available. But the directory listing shows far more than 19MB of files!

Therefore I would guess that the `/boot` filesystem has been corrupted.

Unmount it and check it:

```
umount /boot
fsck -f /boot
```

Comment: fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda2: 304/48672 files (16.4% non-contiguous), 92609/97280 blocks

Comment: `92609/97280 blocks` means that your `/boot` filesystem is almost full; probably some summary information was corrupted, so `df` gave wrong data. Now you can mount `/boot` again and continue with solving the “full `/boot`” problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical ubuntu problem (assuming you have a bunch of older kernels installed), the older installs fill up /boot.

See what the current kernel is:

```
$ uname -a
```

and then which kernels are installed:

```
$ aptitude search linux-image | grep '^i'
```

and then remove a couple of the older unused ones:

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove linux-image-x.x.x-x-type
```

replace x.x.x-x-type with the actual values of the kernel from the second step. Then you should be able to continue with your apt-get install -f step.