# How to remove old kernel on Ubuntu operating system

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, grep, operating-system, dpkg

I am wondering how can I do remove old kernel from Ubuntu operating system.
Please refer image screenshot taken. Please advice. Many thanks.
[list of linux kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLst2.png)

Comment: Just FYI it is much more useful to include text as text in your question (since it can be searched by search engines) than to paste an image.

Answer (score 1):

### To remove old kernel versions on Ubuntu 18.04 or above :

```
sudo apt-get -y --purge autoremove
```

### To remove old Kernel Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and older :

```
sudo -i
apt-get -y --purge remove $(dpkg --list | egrep -i 'linux-image|linux-headers' | awk '/ii/{ print $2}' | egrep -v "$i")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, reboot your PC, and then check the current kernel the OS is using:

```
uname -r && sudo update-grub
```

second, list the kernels

```
dpkg -l | grep linux
```

third, compare the output of the first step with the second step.

finally, `sudo apt purge <all-of-the-old-kernel-name>`

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem on debian 10, this post has solution for ubuntu....very simple and straight forward solution.  worth a look if encountering same/similar issue

https://serverfault.com/a/511726/606964